# Poner el id a un div seleccionándolo por el contenido usando JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Hola necesito una forma en JQUERY de poder ponerle un id al div que contiene el texto **State**, pero no puedo seleccionarlo por la clase, necesitaría que fuera principalmente por el contenido ya que tengo muchísimos div con esa misma clase. Pudieran ayudarme?

```
<div class="directorist-select__container">
    <div class="directorist-select__label">State<i class="la la-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recorrer todos los `div` con el style: `directorist-select__label` y comprobar el texto aplicaría el siguiente método.

**HTML**

```
<div class="directorist-select__container">
    <div class="directorist-select__label">State<i class="la la-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="directorist-select__container">
    <div class="directorist-select__label">State2<i class="la la-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="directorist-select__container">
    <div class="directorist-select__label">State3<i class="la la-angle-down"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
  $(".directorist-select__label").each(function(){
       if($(this).text().trim() === 'State') $(this).attr('id', 'your-id-value');
  });
```

Con esto estoy recorriendo todas las clases `directorist-select__label` y si tiene el texto "State" le agrego el atributo `id`

Comment: Muy agradecido pero quizas no me supe explicar bien. Tengo muchos div con la misma clase pero uno solo contiene el texto State. Necesito seleccionar ese div y ponerle un id.

Comment: @WilfredoPalmaPérez Deberias aclarar mejor cual div con clase queres cambiar, yo me limite al texto "State"

Comment: A este div <div class="directorist-select__label">State<i class="la la-angle-down"></i>
    </div> necesito ponerle un id pero tengo muchos exactamente como el, lo unico diferente es el texto que este dice STATE